ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyTsetlinMachine, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
I am trying to install pyTsetlinMachine using pip install pyTsetlinMachine but it returns this error:
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution ~yspark (C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages)
Collecting PyTsetlinMachine
  Using cached pyTsetlinMachine-0.6.6.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: PyTsetlinMachine
  Building wheel for PyTsetlinMachine (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pyTsetlinMachine
      copying pyTsetlinMachine\tm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pyTsetlinMachine
      copying pyTsetlinMachine\tools.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pyTsetlinMachine
      copying pyTsetlinMachine\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pyTsetlinMachine
      running build_ext
      building 'libTM' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\pyTsetlinMachine
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IpyTsetlinMachine -IC:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /TcpyTsetlinMachine/ConvolutionalTsetlinMachine.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\pyTsetlinMachine/ConvolutionalTsetlinMachine.obj
      ConvolutionalTsetlinMachine.c
      pyTsetlinMachine/ConvolutionalTsetlinMachine.c(175): warning C4013: '__builtin_popcount' undefined; assuming extern returning int
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IpyTsetlinMachine -IC:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /TcpyTsetlinMachine/EmbeddingTsetlinMachine.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\pyTsetlinMachine/EmbeddingTsetlinMachine.obj
      EmbeddingTsetlinMachine.c
      pyTsetlinMachine/EmbeddingTsetlinMachine.c(161): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
      pyTsetlinMachine/EmbeddingTsetlinMachine.c(159): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
      pyTsetlinMachine/EmbeddingTsetlinMachine.c(365): warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IpyTsetlinMachine -IC:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /TcpyTsetlinMachine/IndexedTsetlinMachine.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\pyTsetlinMachine/IndexedTsetlinMachine.obj
      IndexedTsetlinMachine.c
      pyTsetlinMachine/IndexedTsetlinMachine.c(32): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/time.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyTsetlinMachine
  Running setup.py clean for PyTsetlinMachine
Failed to build PyTsetlinMachine
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyTsetlinMachine, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I also tried by downloading the "tar.gz" file and extracting the library folder into the site-packages, but when trying to use it with
import pyTsetlinMachine.tm.MultiClassTsetlinMachine2D it returns this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 16
     13 import cv2
     15 # For Tsetlin Machine
---> 16 import pyTsetlinMachine.tm.MultiClassTsetlinMachine2D

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyTsetlinMachine\tm.py:29
     26 import os
     28 this_dir, this_filename = os.path.split(__file__)
---> 29 _lib = np.ctypeslib.load_library('libTM', os.path.join(this_dir, ".."))    
     31 class CEmbeddingTsetlinMachine(C.Structure):
     32     None

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numpy\ctypeslib.py:161, in load_library(libname, loader_path)
    159             raise
    160 ## if no successful return in the libname_ext loop:
--> 161 raise OSError("no file with expected extension")

OSError: no file with expected extension


"Cannot open include file: 'sys/time.h': No such file or directory" The include file suggests the package is Linux-only.

It seems that this package is for Linux only. The official GitHub repository contains a few issues mentioning installation problems on Windows (same as your error):

cannot install pyTsetlinMachine on windows10? #7
Can't install pyTsetlinMachine #11

The first issue mentions some work-around to get it working on Windows, but it requires quite some effort.
Regarding your second error:
import pyTsetlinMachine.tm.MultiClassTsetlinMachine2D seems wrong. Did you try from pyTsetlinMachine.tm import MultiClassTsetlinMachine2D instead? Although I don't see any MultiClassTsetlinMachine2D in the pyTsetlinMachine.tm module. Are you sure that import statement is correct?
from pyTsetlinMachine.tm import MultiClassTsetlinMachine should work though.
